# What is the grammatical facts of word trained in the following paragraph?

Tags: grammar, participle-phrases

> How can you take advantage of this? A gratitude journal is an easy and
>   actually pretty fun way to keep your attention ***trained*** on what’s
>   important in life: all the beautiful, exciting and wonderful things
>   that surround youday to day but which you may have forggten to
>   appreciate.

The above contents come from the book *The 21 Day of challenge happiness*

As for the bold word, trained, is it a past participle? what is the grammatical facts of it?

According to my research, I think trained on is a past participle phrase which modifies attention. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

*Trained* in this context is a past participle that is being used as an adjective, modifying the direct object *attention*.

You might also call it a [participle adjective](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-adjectives.html).

Comment: What position?  Keep my attention trained, my answer correct, and my drink full.  Full, correct, trained: adjectives all.

Comment: "Trained" is not a past-participial adjective; it's a past participle **verb** in the past-participial clause _your attention trained on what’s important in life ..._ which functions as object of "keep".

Comment: Not sure you're right.  The parts of speech become more obvious if we substitute a word or two, e.g. "A mug is an easy way to keep your coffee warm."  Surely warm is not a verb in that context.  It's an adjective.  Similarly, "A mug is an easy way to keep your coffee warm*ed*" functions exactly the same way, as does "A journal is an easy way to keep your attention trained."  The verb in the participle clause is actually *keep*.  The verb in the main clause is *is*.

Comment: @JohnWu I think Bill J is right. Warm is an adjective, and "warmed" is a particial adjevtive, read [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/warmed). But *train* and *trained* are both verb. A verb in a participle clause cannot be infintive, and *is* is always an auxiliary, it can never be a main verb.

Comment: @user you have to be kidding me.  Warm is both an adjective and a verb, read your own link (scroll down a bit).  Trained can be an adjective (see [this link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trained) which says:  "Adj. 1. **trained** shaped or conditioned or disciplined by training; often used as a combining form; 'a trained mind'; 'trained pigeons'; 'well-trained servants.'")

Comment: Example of "trained" being used as a participle verb: "Having been *trained* by a master, Bruce Lee was undefeatable."

Comment: I have deleted my initial answer and replaced it with one that contains the _correct_ analysis. Sorry for the confusion. cc @user178049

Answer (score 1):

*A gratitude journal is an easy and actually pretty fun way [to keep your attention trained on what’s important in life].*

The bracketed infinitival clause is a complex-transitive clause like *"to keep you warm”.*

*"Trained"* is an adjective taking the PP complement *"on what's important in life"*.

Note that the AdjP does not modify "attention": *"your attention trained on what’s important in life"* is not an NP, not a constituent.

*"Your attention"* is Object and *"trained on what’s important in life"* is a Predicative Complement.

Comment: what does NP stand for？ So trained is the complement of object ‘your attention’， is that right @BillJ？

Comment: NP = noun phrase. Yes, the adjective phrase "trained on what's important in life" is objective Complement. It refers to the noun phrase "your attention".

Comment: Thanks，could you check another question of mine?http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122657/what-is-the-main-idea-of-the-sentence?noredirect=1#comment247113_122657